# "Strike while the iron is hot" - Japanese equivalent

Tags: set-phrases, phrase-requests

Is there an equivalent expression in Japanese for "strike while the iron is hot"?

I've seen a few questions on here with phrases and their equivalents. Does anybody know of a site where these are collated?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is an exact Japanese equivalent to "Strike while the iron is hot," that is "鉄は熱いうちに打て." I don't know whether this proverb had existed before we knew English version, or is just a translation of "Strike while the iron is hot."

Comment: Oh! Pretty much identical.

Comment: @VictorySaber There are lots of direct translations (calques?) of English idioms in Japanese. Another common one is [一石二鳥](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11442/3794)  (killing two birds with one stone). I think most of them entered the language in the Meiji period, but I haven't really researched it.

Comment: I know that one :)    I shall investigate further thank you

Comment: [Both Daijirin and Daijisen](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E9%89%84%E3%81%AF%E7%86%B1%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E3%81%A1%E3%81%AB%E6%89%93%E3%81%A6-576025) list this as a direct translation of the English saying.  I'm not sure if there is any equivalent native kotowaza.

Answer (score 9):

It is 「[鉄]{てつ}は[熱]{あつ}いうちに[打]{う}て」 and every Japanese-speaker would be familiar with this saying.

English to Japanese: http://www.wa.commufa.jp/~anknak/　(Click where it says 「英語ことわざのABC順分類」)

Answer (score 7):

There are a couple of equivalents listed on WWWJDIC. I cannot vouch that these are any common though.

「鉄は熱いうちに[鍛えよ]{きたえよ}」, a variant of the 打て version

「[善]{ぜん}は[急げ]{いそげ}」 *make hay while the sun shines*

「[奇貨居くべし]{きかおくべし}」 *if you find something rare, buy it* (i.e. don't let an opportunity slip)

「[幸運]{こううん}の[女神]{めがみ}は[前髪]{まえがみ}しかない」 *opportunity only knocks once*, lit. the goddess of good fortune has no hair except on her forehead